# XGBRegressor using Pipeline

Tags: python, machine-learning, pipeline, xgboost

I'm using **XGBRegressor** with Pipeline. Pipeline contains preprocessing steps and model (**XGBRegressor**).

Below is complete preprocessing steps. (I have already defined *numeric_cols* and *cat_cols*)

```
numerical_transfer = SimpleImputer()
cat_transfer = Pipeline(steps = [
   ('imputer', SimpleImputer(strategy = 'most_frequent')),
   ('onehot', OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown = 'ignore'))
   ])
preprocessor = ColumnTransformer(
   transformers = [
   ('num', numerical_transfer, numeric_cols),
   ('cat', cat_transfer, cat_cols)
   ])
```

And the final pipeline is

`my_model = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor), ('model', model)])`

When I tried to fit without using ***early_stopping_rounds*** code is working fine.

`(my_model.fit(X_train, y_train))`

But when I use **early_stopping_rounds** as shown below I'm getting error.

`my_model.fit(X_train, y_train, model__early_stopping_rounds=5, model__eval_metric = "mae", model__eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)])`

I'm getting error at:

```
 model__eval_set=[(X_valid, y_valid)]) and the error is

ValueError: DataFrame.dtypes for data must be int, float or bool.
Did not expect the data types in fields MSZoning, Street, Alley, LotShape, LandContour, Utilities, LotConfig, LandSlope, Condition1, Condition2, BldgType, HouseStyle, RoofStyle, RoofMatl, MasVnrType, ExterQual, ExterCond, Foundation, BsmtQual, BsmtCond, BsmtExposure, BsmtFinType1, BsmtFinType2, Heating, HeatingQC, CentralAir, Electrical, KitchenQual, Functional, FireplaceQu, GarageType, GarageFinish, GarageQual, GarageCond, PavedDrive, PoolQC, Fence, MiscFeature, SaleType, SaleCondition
```

Did it mean that I should preprocess X_valid before applying to my_model.fit() or I have done something wrong ?

If the problem is we need to preprocess X_valid before applying fit() how to do that with preprocessor I have defined above ?

Edit : I tried to preprocess X_valid without Pipeline, but I got error saying feature mismatch.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that pipelines do not fit eval_set. So, as you said, you need to preprocess X_valid. To do that the easiest way is using your pipeline without the 'model' step. Use the following code before fitting your pipeline:

```
# Make a copy to avoid changing original data
X_valid_eval=X_valid.copy()
# Remove the model from pipeline
eval_set_pipe = Pipeline(steps = [('preprocessor', preprocessor)])
# fit transform X_valid.copy()
X_valid_eval = eval_set_pipe.fit(X_train, y_train).transform (X_valid_eval)
```

Then fit your pipeline after changing model__eval_set as follows:

```
my_model.fit(X_train, y_train, model__early_stopping_rounds=5, model__eval_metric = "mae", model__eval_set=[(X_valid_eval, y_valid)])
```

Comment: If i'm not wrong, we also need to transform `X_train` like the way we transformed `X_valid`.

Comment: No, you do not need to transform X_train. The pipeline already handles that for us.